# Creating trigger pulses of equal amplitude to voltage pulses

Tags: python

I'm trying to do basically what the title says. I have a series of pulses for which I have produced a rectangular 'trigger' pulse for when the rising edge passes a threshold. Although so far I've only been able to create these trigger pulses of constant amplitude. I have an array of the amplitudes of the pulses (pulseheight) and an array of the trigger indices (triggersLED), both of which have 1000 elements in them each. I am trying to write my code such that the trigger pulse amplitude will be equal to the pulseheight value for each element . I've added my code down below but when plotting the trigger pulses they are of constant height and not of equal height to the incoming pulses.
The first 5 pulseheight values are [0.0448, 0.0416, 0.0204, 0.0328, 0.068]
And the first 5 trigger indices [9762, 49775, 89872, 129843, 169753]

e.g. I want the first trigger pulse to occur at 9762 and be of height 0.0448.  Meaning that cLED will have zeros up to the 9761 index then values of 0.0448 for the next 4000 indices and back to zero.  Then the next trigger to occur at 49775 and of height 0.0416 and so on...
The width of these trigger pulses are not important (I have set it to 4000 in my code).

```
cLED = np.zeros(4000000)

for a in range(1000):

    for b in triggersLED:

        cLED[b:b+4000] = pulseheight[a]
```

Comment: Please read [mre]. Your question should include examples of all the data you are operating on. What is `pulseheight`?. It looks like you are not trying to determine the amplitude of the original pulse - that is one reason your triggers are not correct.  What part of the process are you having trouble with? If you have already made attempts to determine the original amplitude, you should show that. As-is your question is lacking information.

Comment: `when the rising edge passes a threshold` - your example doesn't look like it is filtering for this criteria. Is that what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I have already determined the amplitude of the original pulses, these are the values in the array called 'pulseheight'.  I am wanting to set the trigger pulse height equal to the corresponding values in pulseheight

Comment: You need to provide **minimal** examples of `triggersLED`, `pulseheight`, and your expected result for `cLED` with those inputs. Please read [mre].

Comment: I added a couple more variations to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but there is probably a better way. Iterate over the indices and amplitudes and assign to slices.

```
import numpy as np
pulseheight = np.array([0.0448, 0.0416, 0.0204, 0.0328, 0.068])
trigger = np.array([9, 49, 89, 129, 169]) 
width = 4
cLED = np.zeros(200)

for i,a in zip(trigger,pulseheight):
    cLED[i:i+width] = a
```

---

Variation: may not be any better.

```
cleds = np.split(cLED,trigger)

for i,a in enumerate(cleds[1:]):
    a[:width] = pulseheight[i]

cleds = np.concatenate(cleds)
```

---

Try to get rid of the python for loop. Split `cLED` on the trigger indices; pad the resultant arrays to the same width so they can be concatenated to a 2d array;
make the assignment; flatten and remove the `nan`'s.

```
pad_width = np.diff(trigger).max()
cleds = np.vstack((np.pad(a,(0,pad_width-len(a)),constant_values=np.nan) for a in cleds))
cleds[1:,:4] = pulseheight[:,None]
cleds = np.ravel(cleds)
cleds = cleds[~np.isnan(cleds)]
```

---

Another variation using a Pandas Dataframe which ends up having sparse rows so when the data is *recombined* the `nan` fill values need to be removed.  Uses assignment to a slice and broadcasting.

```
import pandas as pd
# using arrays defined above
cleds = np.split(cLED,trigger)
df = pd.DataFrame(cleds)
df.iloc[1:,:4] = pulseheight[:,None]
q = np.concatenate(df.values)
q = q[~np.isnan(q)]
```

---

I really have no feel for which is *best*.